# How can I post to a Facebook Page using the page's voice?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, laravel-5

I am writing a Laravel 5 application which should post a new link to its corresponding facebook page whenever a new post is made on the site. I am having a lot of difficulty getting it going because I am running into confusions with access tokens.

I know that to post to the page in its own voice, I need a page access token with the 'publish_pages' permission.

I am sure that I'm approaching this the wrong way, and have no clue how to use a page token that I've retrieved once I have it. I was able to get a page token by doing the following:

```
        if($session) {
        try {
            $request = (new FacebookRequest(
                $session, 'GET', '/me/accounts', null
                )
            )->execute()->getGraphObject();
            $request = $request->getProperty('data');
            $page = $request->getProperty(0);
            $pageAccessToken = $page->getProperty('access_token');
            var_dump($pageAccessToken);
        } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
            echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
            echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Now I'm clueless as to how to use this access token. Do I have to perform another API call in the same method to do the actual posting of the link?

Overall, I'm a little confused as the documentation expects that you will have users using their credentials to login to your app. I only want this application connected to one Facebook account, the administrator's, to post updates from the site. Would I use an app access token for such a task instead?

Comment: You need a page token, how do you get a page token? By authenticating a user that is admin of that page. After that you just can start posting into facebook using the graph API passing the page token. Basically you are saying is, "I want to post as a page here's a page token that shows that I have permissions for that". Does that makes sense now? You must have to make a request to get the token, after that you can start doing requests in the name of the page, such as posting

Comment: _“and have no clue how to use a page token that I've retrieved once I have it”_ – you create a `FacebookSession` instance using the access token, and then you use that with `FacebookRequest` to make the post …